# Set Index- / Search-Parameters of FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have a question concerning javaCVs FlannBasedMatcher. In the openCV documentation, it is possible to supply an index / search parameter to the constructor, in java it doesn't work. So how can i do it if not via the constructor?

```
FlannBasedMatcher flannMatcher = new FlannBasedMatcher(indexParams, searchParams); // Doesn't work for me
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the lines that enable the constructor to use the index- and searchParameters were commented out. The new release of javaCV will have that constructor as well!